# PowerShell read text file line by line and find missing file in folders

Tags: powershell

I am a novice looking for some assistance. I have a text file containing two columns of data. One column is the Vendor and one is the Invoice. 
I need to scan that text file, line by line, and see if there is a match on Vendor and Invoice in a path. In the path, $Location, the first wildcard is the Vendor number and the second wildcard is the Invoice
I want the non-matches output to a text file.

```
$Location = "I:\\Vendors\*\Invoices\*"
$txt = "C:\\Users\sbagford.RECOEQUIP\Desktop\AP.txt"
$Output ="I:\\Vendors\Missing\Missing.txt"
foreach ($line in Get-Content $txt) {
if (-not($line -match $location)){$line}
}
set-content $Output -value $Line
```

Sample Data from txt or csv file.

```
kvendnum    wapinvoice
000953  90269211
000953  90238674
001072  11012016
002317  448668
002419  06123711
002419  06137343
002419  06134382
002419  759208
002419  753087
002419  753069
002419  762614
003138  N6009348
003138  N6009552
003138  N6009569
003138  N6009612
003182  770016
003182  768995
003182  06133429
```

In above data the only match is on the second line: 000953  90238674
and the 6th line: 002419    06137343

Comment: You're using wildcard syntax with the -match operator which is expecting a regular expression.  Use -like or -notlike with wildcards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but here's how I'd approach it:

```
$Location = "I:\\Vendors\\.+\\Invoices\\.+"
$txt = "C:\\Users\sbagford.RECOEQUIP\Desktop\AP.txt"
$Output ="I:\\Vendors\Missing\Missing.txt"
select-string -path $txt -pattern $Location -notMatch |
    set-content $Output
```

There's no need to pick through the file line-by-line; PowerShell can do this for you using `select-string`. The `-notMatch` parameter simply inverts the search and sends through any lines that don't match the pattern.

`select-string` sends out a stream of `matchinfo` objects that contain the lines that met the search conditions. These objects actually contain far more information that just the matching line, but fortunately PowerShell is smart enough to know how to send the relevant item through to `set-content`.

Regular expressions can be tricky to get right, but are worth getting your head around if you're going to do tasks like this.

EDIT

```
$Location  = "I:\Vendors\{0}\Invoices\{1}.pdf"
$txt = "C:\\Users\sbagford.RECOEQUIP\Desktop\AP.txt"
$Output  = "I:\Vendors\Missing\Missing.txt"

get-content -path $txt | 
    % {

        # extract fields from the line
        $lineItems = $_ -split "  "

        # construct path based on fields from the line
        $testPath = $Location -f $lineItems[0], $lineItems[1]

        # for debugging purposes
        write-host ( "Line:'{0}'  Path:'{1}'" -f $_, $testPath )

        # test for existence of the path; ignore errors
        if ( -not ( get-item -path $testPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) ) {
            # path does not exist, so write the line to pipeline
            write-output $_ 

        }

    } |
    Set-Content -Path $Output
```

I guess we will have to pick through the file line-by-line after all. If there is a more idiomatic way to do this, it eludes me.

Code above assumes a consistent format in the input file, and uses `-split` to break the line into an array.

EDIT - version 3

```
$Location  = "I:\Vendors\{0}\Invoices\{1}.pdf"
$txt = "C:\\Users\sbagford.RECOEQUIP\Desktop\AP.txt"
$Output  = "I:\Vendors\Missing\Missing.txt"

get-content -path $txt | 
    select-string "(\S+)\s+(\S+)" | 
    %{

        # pull vendor and invoice numbers from matchinfo     
        $vendor = $_.matches[0].groups[1]
        $invoice = $_.matches[0].groups[2]

        # construct path
        $testPath = $Location -f $vendor, $invoice

        # for debugging purposes
        write-host ( "Line:'{0}'  Path:'{1}'" -f $_.line, $testPath )

        # test for existence of the path; ignore errors
        if ( -not ( get-item -path $testPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) ) {
            # path does not exist, so write the line to pipeline
            write-output $_ 
        }

    } |
    Set-Content -Path $Output
```

It seemed that the `-split "  "` behaved differently in a running script to how it behaves on the command line. Weird. Anyway, this version uses a regular expression to parse the input line. I tested it against the example data in the original post and it seemed to work.

The regex is broken down as follows

```
(     Start the first matching group
\S+   Greedily match one or more non-white-space characters
)     End the first matching group
\s+   Greedily match one or more white-space characters
(     Start the second matching group
\S+   Greedily match one or more non-white-space characters
)     End the second matching groups
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down, very informative. It is reading each line and it is outputting to the $Output path but it is not outputting only the non-matched items, or the missing. It is writing all lines from $txt into the output.

Comment: So I removed the Vendor column from my $txt file and kept only the Invoice column. It is working now and outputting only non-matching lines from $txt. This will work fine unless I have a duplicate Invoice under two different Vendors. Any suggestions to make it verify both Vendor and Invoice? Also, I looked up the .+ but I still don't understand what it is doing. Can you give me more clarification?

Comment: I have attempted to fix the problem with it not matching on both, but it isn't outputting anything. Please take a look.

Comment: $Location = "I:\\Vendors\\.+\\Invoices\\.+"
$txt = "C:\\Users\sbagford.RECOEQUIP\Desktop\AP.csv"
$Output ="I:\\Vendors\Missing\Missing2.txt"
$DB = import-csv $txt 
foreach ($Line in $DB) 
{
$First = $Line.kvendnum
$Second = $Line.wapinvoice
write-host "Vend is: "$First
write-host "Inv is: "$Second
Write-Host ""} 
If( ($First -match $Location) -and
($Second -notmatch $Location)) { set-content $Output}

Comment: Can you update the question with some example content from the text file, indicating which lines should be included/excluded.

Comment: The '.+' simply matches one or more characters.

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Comment: OK; so you're matching text file contents with files/paths on the file system, and you want to see every line where there is no corresponding file/path?

Comment: Correct. The Location has the kvendum from the text file in the file path after Invoices\. The wapinvoice is the last wildcard in the path. It is a pdf file.

Comment: Strike that it does not work. I removed the error action to see what errors it was giving. get-item : Illegal characters in path.
At line:15 char:21
+         if ( -not ( get-item -path $testPath  ) ) {
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (I:\Vendors\000015 2183375\Invoices\.pdf:String) [Get-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

Comment: Could be a couple of things. Problem with input file, perhaps, or problem with the simplistic parsing (the '-split'). Maybe add aa 'write-host' line to display the original line and the contents of the first two members of the '$lineItems' array.

Comment: I reran it with only ten lines of data in the Text file and it still gives the same errors. In the output file it post all lines in the array. It is not matching on anything.